# transition_post_status hook doesn't have any POST data when publish with Gutenberg

Tags: posts, block-editor, publish

**Describe the bug**

When placing a hook on transition_post_status I can see it fired but no POST data is available, to get that post data I have to use the save_post hook which is inconvenient since I don't get the $new_status and $old_status infos.

**To Reproduce**

1. Hook into transition_post_status. Something like the following code in functions.php will do the job:

> ```
> add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'log_data', 10, 3 );
>
>     function log_data( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
>         error_log(json_encode($_POST));
>     }
> ```

2. Create a new Gutenberg post and publish it

https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/12897

Comment: This is something to take up with the Gutenberg developers, as you and others have done at the linked Github issue. I'm not sure what you want to accomplish by posting it here.

Comment: Not all aware of this Github post, I want to ask developers here about this issue and if the issue will solve in Github people will know by follow the link.

Answer (score 4):

But you shouldn't use `$_POST` inside that hook.

[`transition_post_status`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/transition_post_status/) fires when a post is transitioned from one status to another.

It can be caused by anything (not only by sending POST request from editor).

For example here's the function that is responsible for publishing future posts: [`check_and_publish_future_post`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.0.3/src/wp-includes/post.php#L3872). It's called only by cron, without sending any POST data at all...

`transition_post_status` hook takes 3 params:

> **$new_status** (string) New post status.
>
> **$old_status** (string) Old post status.
>
> **$post** (WP_Post) Post object.

and you should use mainly these values in your action - you can be certain that they will be passed and will be correct.

You can't assume anything about the contents of POST request...

Comment: publish_future_post hook not trigger when post publish

Comment: Yes it is - just take a look at the second link in my answer - this is the function that is used as callback for `publish_future_post` schedule event, and you can clearly see that it uses status transitions inside of it.